# Auto Rotate Dynamic UIViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a scenario where I'm creating the `UIViewcontrollers` dynamically and adding a UIView on top of it and pushing it to the navigation stack. This is how I have created my `view Controller`

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
[vc.view addSubView:customView];
[self.navigationController pushViewController vc];
```

When running my App on the device, my view doesn't autorotate. (If the VC had a implementation file, I would have returned `YES` in `shouldAutorotate` to make it work.)
Any pointers/help is appreciated.

EdITed based on George's Reply:

George's code works perfectly for ios6 and above. `supportedInterfaceOrientations` API has been made available for ios6.0+, Looking for a general fix for ios4.3+
Thanks..

Comment: "To support additional orientations, you must override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and return YES for any orientations your subclass supports. If the autoresizing properties of your views are configured correctly, that may be all you have to do." (c) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

If your navigation controller is a rootviewcontroller than add this category to the place you created it, if it doesn't help that add to the viewcontroller which must rotate

```
@implementation UINavigationController(Rotate)

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;    
}

@end
```

also may be your forgot to add in your app delegate

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

### Edit:

For iOS 5 you need only to add this method to needed viewcontroller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks George for replying, I have edited my question. Your suggestion did work. But it DOESN'T WORK for ios 5

Comment: You should add this method in all your viewcontrollers- not just the container viewcontroller. - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this delegate in your viewcontroller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Kiran, if you create a file which inherits UIViewController, you can see in the .m file required delegates only implemented (You can also see the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" method commented by default). By default the interface orientation delegate methods not implemented because they are optional. Here you are creating an instance of UIViewController, since these delegates are not implemented, your orientation changes will not reflect in it. Hope now its clear for you :)

Comment: Yes Augustine, I clearly understand this fact that I am creating an instance of UIViewController and its delegates are not implemented. Is there a way to achieve it without creating .h and .m files ?

Comment: Kiran, I dont understand why you are simply creating an instance of UIViewController. Without inheriting UIViewController, u cannot implement the autoRotate delegates. So I think autoRotation may not work properly if you are not handled it.